# How to get a shortcut to insert labels and cross-references in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2019

I regularly have to insert labels in MS Word 365 desktop application in documents and cross-reference their text. I apply them to legal definitions in contracts, and cross-referencing ensures that the the terms are used correctly throughout the whole document.

I apply labels with the ribbon: *Insert* > *Hyperlink* > *Label* (*Вставлення* > *Посилання* > *Закладка* in my interface language). Is it possible to open the dialogue for assigning a label with a keyboard shortcut?

I used to cross-reference with the ribbon too: *Insert* > *Hyperlink* > *Cross-reference* > *Label* (*Вставлення* > *Посилання* > *Перехресне посилання* > *Закладка* in my interface language). I has just succeeded assigning a custom shortcut to open *Cross-reference* dialogue in custom shortcuts settings (in the ribbon configuration section in MS Word options). But I still have to switch to labels every time when I inserted a different type of cross-reference (such as cross-reference to a paragraph) before. Is it possible to open the dialogue and have it ready at labels with a single keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To insert cross-references: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>+<kbd>RF</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>RF</kbd>

To insert a caption: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

These shortcuts work with English, they will be different in your native language. To find out the correct sequence, type <kbd>ALT</kbd>, then follow the key hints, which appear on the ribbon, to navigate it. If a subsection of the ribbon is wrapped, so you have to press the down arrow to get to the required option, than you may try to skip the letters for that options group. Skipping works only if the group would not be wrapped on a bigger screen which fits more options. For example, to insert cross-reference in Ukrainian interface: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Щ</kbd>+(<kbd>Я</kbd>+<kbd>Л</kbd>)+<kbd>Х</kbd>, where <kbd>Я</kbd>+<kbd>Л</kbd> can be skipped safely.

To get a shorter keyboard sequence for the command which you use really frequently, you can add the command to the Quick Access Toolbar at the top of the window. Right-click the command on the ribbon and choose `Add to Quick Access Toolbar`. Now, that command is available with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> or a different number key, depending on its position on the Quick Access Toolbar.

Using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, which is usually at the right, does not work with any of the above.

You can press the keys simultaneously or sequentially, but only sequentially if you use the numpad for numbers when pressing the shortcut keys combination (because the numpad has its own Alt key combinations).